# Starting a game - Tetris infinite runner?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

Having trouble describing what I'm looking for - essentially, I'm classed as a beginner at unity, I've only made artwork for games, never created the core myself.

**Preface:** Here's game in a nutshell:

- The camera is looking down with an Orthographic angle
- The ground in scrolling down the screen, you're walking towards the top of the screen. In essence, you're on a treadmill.
- As you walk/progress, shapes start entering the screen, like Tetris.
- You simply walk over to that shape, pick it up and take it 1 of 3 baskets on the - left side of the screen.
- Repeat until end of level

**Help:**

How would I start, what should I start with?
Do I seek out examples and guides on creating an endless runner, even though the game has more similarities to Tetris but with interactions? Because of this, I'm lost for words on what to search for in order to gain the knowledge to build what I'm thinking.

**Background:**

I'm coming from an Artistic background, I work with web development daily, so I think I'll be able to grasp the basics quick enough, I just need that finger pointing at the obvious!

Comment: Please, read carefully the article about [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) (especially point #4)

Comment: I've rephrased the question to not ask specifically for links, but for assistance. If that helps remove the -1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that you're coming from a web development background I can see why you're looking for hoping to find pinpointed resources for your specific game. Web development generally involves finding specific ways to tackle each specific problem you encounter.

One thing you will want to be aware of is that Unity development is a bit different in that most things are built using the core set of basic fundamentals. Because of this I would actually recommend looking into tutorials that will teach you about the basics rather than trying to find something specific for what it is you're building, as you will be able to apply these basics to encounter any of the problems you encounter a long the way. The basic Unity tutorials provided by the Unity team do a great job of teaching these basics: [The Unity Tutorials Page](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials)

At the very least the Roll-A-Ball tutorial should teach you most of the basics as it pertains to how objects work, creating scripts, etc.

After you are a bit more comfortable with Unity in general, then I would suggest looking into some more focused tutorials that are a bit closer to what you want to do as these will give you a better idea of how you can apply the basics you've learned. One recommendation I would have for the game you're trying to make is 
[this runner tutorial by Catlike Coding.](http://catlikecoding.com/unity/tutorials/runner/)

While the game you'll be creating in that tutorial will play quite differently than what you're describing, this should give you a better idea of how you can approach some of the challenges that you'll encounter in the development of your game (things like continually creating objects).

Comment: Fantastic, and you're right, I don't need to know everything about javascript to be able to build what I want usually, which is sort of the beauty of web design, but with Games, I'm usually only creating assets, so it's this hurdle of how do I do this myself without needing to send it over for coding.

Comment: I'll continue through the tutorials :)